# Ubuntu VirtualBox SSH between two machines Permission Denied (Public key, Password)

Tags: server, virtualbox, ssh

I have 2 Ubuntu virtual machines on same network with Internal network cards. Both machines can ping each other. both have port TCP/22 open for ssh. I can't SSH either one from each other. Error I get is permission denied (Public key, Password). When I turn password authentication off and even when I turn PasswordProtection, PubKeyAuthentication, RSA Authentication to 'NO', I get permission denied () error.

Transferring keys get the same error.

Comment: Do you have `openssh-server` installed on both?

Comment: can you add debug log ? (ssh -vvv from one host )